# No thumbnails for mp3 files in 18.04 (Nautilus)

Tags: nautilus, gnome-shell, thumbnails, nautilus-extensions, mp3-tag

When I edit a music file in mp3 format, I insert an image with easytag. When I play the file, the multimedia player (vlc, rhythmbox, smplayer...) does show me the cover of the file that I inserted previously. However, in nautilus the covers don't appear, in KDE with Dolphin I don't have problems, with Cinnamon and nemo neither, it only happens in nautilus with Gnome Shell. Can someone tell me if I'm missing a file or something or how to fix the problem?

Comment: Testing myself I see I have the embedded artwork in Nautilus. This is in Ubuntu 18.10, but the nautilus version is still the same as Ubuntu 18.04, i.e. 3.26.4.

Answer (score 3):

I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg ffmpegthumbnailer gstreamer1.0-libav totem
```

if as a result of executing this your thumbnails don't start appearing immediately, then try the following:

```
nautilus -q
```

(This will kill the nautilus file manager, so then restart it by opening "files".)

If that does not work either, then try logging out and then back in.

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu 20.04.